# Get rid of the read delay after holding a key

Tags: bash, shell

I'm not going to provide my exact code, only the important thing.

```bash
while :; do
  read -sn 1 foo
done
```

If you hold down a button, the cursor stops blinking (which probably means it's processing all of the characters). And, it has a bunch of keys built up, and it has to go through all of that in order to continue blinking, which means it is waiting for input (I think.)

How do I prevent this?

I don't know if I explained this well enough, I hope you understand my question.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you talking about turning off the keyboard type-ahead buffer? Perhaps making a reproducible case would help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define a test for the exit condition, namely a successful capture of character, so ... if you are holding the key down, you are collecting multiple characters until the keyboard buffer forces output (long stream), but it is still looping until you kill the script/command.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
  read -sn 1 foo
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then break ; fi
done

echo "Out - character = ${foo}"
```